# python datetime localization

Tags: python

What do I need to do (modules to load, locale methods to invoke, etc.) so that when I call:

```
datetime.date(2009,1,16).strftime("%A %Y-%b-%d")
```

instead of getting:

```
Out[20]: 'Friday 2009-Jan-16'
```

i get spanish/french/german/... output

```
Out[20]: 'Viernes 2009-Ene-16'
```

without having to change my whole operating system's locale (i.e. just use python calls to dynamically set the locale and keep the changes scoped within my app)

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`locale.setlocale()`](http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html#locale.setlocale)

Comment: sorry for the basic question, but how do you set it?     

'spanish' in locale.locale_alias.keys()
True


locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'spanish')
Error: unsupported locale setting

Comment: `locale.setlocale(local.LC_TIME, 'es_ES')`

Comment: tried
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'es_ES')
and still get
    Error: unsupported locale setting

Comment: Then for some reason your operating system's locale entries are missing.

Comment: That's a hardcoded mapping; it doesn't look at your OS to figure out what it knows about.

Comment: got it; thanks for your help; will try to figure out my ubuntu's locale settings and follow up on this thread

Comment: sudo locale-gen es_ES.UTF-8 did the trick; now your answer worked;
thanks.

Comment: @jd.: note: [`es_ES.UTF-8` doesn't support am/pm on my system](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23201158/4279)

Comment: I am using Debian and  "locale-gen es_ES.UTF-8" didn't work. I added the spanish local via "sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales" as shown [here](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Table_of_locales)

Answer (score 6):

On Ubuntu,

```
$> sudo locale-gen es_ES.UTF-8
$> sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
$> python
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'es_ES.UTF-8')
```

Answer (score 4):

Also, have a look at the [babel](http://babel.edgewall.org/) project.

Answer (score 2):

After setting your locale (with `locale.setlocale`) You can use the `locale` modules' `nl_langinfo` method like so:

```
time.strftime(locale.nl_langinfo(locale.D_T_FMT), time.localtime())
```